# How to get custom response headers on web using dio?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dio

I doing a Flutter app and I using dio to connect app with my web service.
When I want to access to custom headers in response, on mobile I don't have any problem, but this headers on web not be available and  get different.

My code:

```
  final dio = Dio();
  final response = await dio.getUri(requestUri,
      options: Options(headers: {
        'authorization': 'Bearer ${credentials!.accessToken}',
      }));
```

How I do to on web and mobile get a same custom headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), part of the browser built-in cross-site security restrictions. Your server need to include your custom headers into the "preflight" OPTIONS response header [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) to allow your browser to see those headers.

For example, https://discuss.istio.io/t/configuring-cors/7458/5